# Crank-Nicolson code for in-situ combustion model (MATLAB)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, matlab, mathematical-modeling, programming

I need to solve in MATLAB the following system (1):

> \begin{align}
> &\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial t} + u \frac{\partial (\rho\theta)}{\partial x} = \frac{1}{\text{Pe}_T} \frac{\partial^2 \theta}{\partial x^2} + \Phi, \tag{15}\\
> &\frac{\partial \eta}{\partial t} = \Phi , \tag{16}\\
> & \rho = \theta_0/(\theta + \theta_0) , \tag{17}\\
> & \Phi = \beta (1-\eta)\exp\left(-\frac{\mathcal E}{\theta + \theta_0}\right) \tag{18}
> \end{align}

And for it I would like to use these datas and scheme (Crank-Nicolson)

[image]

With the boundary condition $\theta(x_0,t) = 0$ and $\eta(x_0,t) = 1$ at $x_0 = 0$ for $t\geq 0$.

I really do not know how I can do this on MATLAB. I tried to put on MATLAB all my datas, as you can see but I do not know as I can finish.

About this code I have got the following error: `Line: 74` `Assignment to x not supported. Variable has the same name as a local function.`

Follow the code. I've got a hard activity and I don't have experience on MATLAB, indeed my deadline is hard, so I'm sorry for my mistakes.

Many thanks for any help!

```
tic
clear all
close all
%% INPUT PARAMETERS
xmax=0.05; % x maximal value
xmin=0; % x maximal value
tmax=0.008; % x maximal value
tmin=0; % x maximal value
dt=10^(-5); % time step value
tol=10^(-6); % precison on the staionnary solution
Pet=1406;
beta=7.44*10^(10);
epsilon=93.8;
theta0=3.67;
u=3.76;
phi==beta*(1-eta)*e^(-epsilon/(theta+theta0));
rho==theta0/(theta+theta0);
V0==[theta;eta];
% discretise the domain
dX=(xmax-xmin)/500;


%%
V=V0;
VCN=V
%% 

% Initial conditions
for i=0: 800;
    if x==0; 
    theta(x,t(i))==0;
    eta(x,t(i))==1;
    end 
end

for i=0: 800;
    if t==0;
    theta(x(i),t)==0;
    eta(x(i),t)==0;
    end 
end

% loop through time
nsteps= tmax/dt;
 for n=1 : nsteps


    % calculate the scheme
    for i = 1 : 800
        for j=1 : 800

           theta(x(j),t(i+1))+u*dt*(1/(4*dX))*(rho(x(j+1),t(i+1))*theta(x(j+1),t(i+1))-rho(x(j-1),t(i+1))*theta(x(j-1),t(i+1)))-(dt/(2*Pet*dX*dX))*(theta(x(j-1),t(i+1))-theta(x(j),t(i+1))+theta(x(j+1),t(i+1)))-(dt/2)*phi(x(j),t(i+1))== theta(x(j),t(i))-u*dt*(1/(4*dX))*(rho(x(j+1),t(i))*theta(x(j+1),t(i))-rho(x(j-1),t(i))*theta(x(j-1),t(i)))+ (dt/(Pet*2*dX*dX))*(theta(x(j-1),t(i))-2*theta(x(j),t(i))+theta(x(j+1),t(i)))+(dt/2)*phi(x(j),t(i));


           (dt/2)*phi(x(j),t(i+1))+eta(x(j),t(i+1))== eta(x(j),t(i))-(dt/2)*phi(x(j),t(i));

        end
    end

    % update V

    V=VCN;
 end 


 % plot solution
    set(fig,'YData',V(1,:));
    set(tit,'String',strcat('n =',num2str(n)));
    drawnow;



function x=x(j);
x(j)=j*dx 
end

function t=t(i);
t(i)=i*dt 
end

function eta=eta(x,t);
end

function theta=theta(x,t);
end

function phi=phi(x,t);
phi(x,t)=beta*(1-eta(x,t))*e^(-epsilon/(theta(x,t)+theta0));
end
```

---

(1) G. Chapiro, A.E.R. Gutierrez, J. Herskovits, S.R. Mazorche, W.S. Pereira (2016): "Numerical Solution of a Class of Moving BoundaryProblems with a Nonlinear Complementarity Approach", *J. Optim. Theory Appl.* **168**(2), 534-550. [doi:10.1007/s10957-015-0816-7](https://doi.org/10.1007/s10957-015-0816-7)

Comment: Don't just post pictures of equations and text; it is not searchable for future users who may have the same or a similar question. Take the time to transcribe correctly what you're asking.

Comment: @TonyS.F. Sorry for the failure. For various reasons I have been very busy and could not do as I should. However, in a few days I will be rewriting the post and typing as needed. I make this commitment. Thank you very much for your attention!

Comment: @TonyS.F. I thank Harry49 for the help with the equations and hope the post is OK now. The other equations I think it's interesting if we see as they are at the article. Many thanks and sorry once again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us introduce the vector ${\bf U} = (\theta, \eta)^\top$ of unknowns. Since $\partial_t {\bf U}$ is nonlinear in ${\bf U}$, the Crank-Nicolson method requires to invert the nonlinear algebraic system $F_\Delta (\theta,\eta) = 0$ from Eq. (30) at each time step. This step provides the updated values ${\bf U}_m^{n+1}$ from the current values ${\bf U}_m^{n}$. The discrete version of $\partial_t \eta = \Phi$ writes $F^2_\Delta (\theta, \eta) = 0$, where
$$
F^2_\Delta (\theta, \eta) = \eta_m^{n+1} - \eta_m^n - \frac{\Delta t}{2} \left(\Phi_m^{n+1} + \Phi_m^n\right)
$$
(note the sign mistake in Eq. (32)). We introduce the function $\varphi$ of the variable $\theta$ such that $\Phi = (1-\eta) \varphi$. Thus, $F^2_\Delta (\theta, \eta) = 0$ can be solved analytically, providing
$$
\eta_m^{n+1} = \frac{\eta_m^{n} + \frac12 {\Delta t}\, (\Phi_m^n + \varphi_m^{n+1})}{1 + \frac12 {\Delta t}\, \varphi_m^{n+1}} \, .
$$
In the general case, only the equation $F^1_\Delta (\theta, \eta) = 0$ remains to solve with respect to the unknown $\theta_m^{n+1}$. Introducing the function $f = \rho\theta$ of the variable $\theta$, one may write
\begin{aligned}
F^1_\Delta (\theta, \eta) &= \theta_m^{n+1} - \theta_m^n + u\frac{\Delta t}{4\, \Delta x} \left(f_{m+1}^{n+1} - f_{m-1}^{n+1} + f_{m+1}^{n} - f_{m-1}^{n}\right) \\
& - \frac{\Delta t}{2\, \text{Pe}_T \, \Delta x^2} \left(\theta_{m+1}^{n+1} - 2\theta_{m}^{n+1} + \theta_{m-1}^{n+1} + \theta_{m+1}^{n} - 2\theta_{m}^{n} + \theta_{m-1}^{n}\right) \\
& - \frac{\Delta t}{2} \left(\Phi_m^{n+1} + \Phi_m^n\right) 
\end{aligned}
(note the typo in Eq. (31)).
The Crank-Nicolson method can be implemented in Matlab with `fsolve` from the Optimization Toolbox as follows:

```
global Un Pe Beta E theta0 u dt dx

Pe = 1406;
Beta = 7.44e10;
E = 93.8;
theta0 = 3.67;
u = 3.76;

dt = 0.03;
dx = 0.1;
x = 0:dx:10;
M = length(x);
tf = 0.5;

Un = [zeros(1,M); zeros(1,M)];
t = 0;

hp = plot(x,Un(1,:));
ylim([0 1]);

while t<tf
    Un = fsolve(@fun,Un);
    Un(:,1) = [0; 1];
    Un(:,end) = Un(:,end-1);
    t = t + dt;
    set(hp,'YData',Un(1,:));
    drawnow;
end
```

with the function `fun.m` defined by

```
function FDelta = fun(Unp1)

    global Un Pe Beta E theta0 u dt dx

    ULn = circshift(Un,[0 1]);
    URn = circshift(Un,[0 -1]);
    rhotLn = theta0*ULn(1,:)./(ULn(1,:)+theta0);
    rhotRn = theta0*URn(1,:)./(URn(1,:)+theta0);
    Phin = Beta*(1-Un(2,:)).*exp(-E./(Un(1,:)+theta0));
    Dn = [-u*(rhotRn-rhotLn)/(2*dx) + (URn(1,:)-Un(1,:)+ULn(1,:))/(Pe*dx^2) + Phin; Phin];

    ULnp1 = circshift(Unp1,[0 1]);
    URnp1 = circshift(Unp1,[0 -1]);
    fLnp1 = theta0*ULnp1(1,:)./(ULnp1(1,:)+theta0);
    fRnp1 = theta0*URnp1(1,:)./(URnp1(1,:)+theta0);
    Phinp1 = Beta*(1-Unp1(2,:)).*exp(-E./(Unp1(1,:)+theta0));
    Dnp1 = [-u*(fRnp1-fLnp1)/(2*dx) + (URnp1(1,:)-Unp1(1,:)+ULnp1(1,:))/(Pe*dx^2) + Phinp1; Phinp1];

    FDelta = Unp1 - Un - 0.5*dt*(Dn+Dnp1);
end
```

The Matlab implementation above is not optimal since it doesn't exploit the expression of $\eta_m^{n+1}$. Nevertheless, it must have less programming weaknesses than OP's version, which includes basic Matlab programming mistakes such as duplicate names, inappropriate assignments, data types, and scheme implementation.

Comment: Many thanks once again, Harry49. I've had a problem with the expiration of my free test license and could not check yet, but I am studying and will test as soon as I can. Many thanks, you are helping me a lot at the beginning of my Master program.

Comment: I've tried to run the code and tried also change the values:dt = 0.00001;
dx = 0.0005;
x = 0:dx:0.05;
M = length(x);
tf = 0.008; to try repeat the results at the article. As you said, the solution seems to remain constant in time even in this small space (or is something wrong by here since I'm using the Octave now). The authors don't get a constant solution.

Comment: @Na'omi Actually it is not an initial condition, it is boundary condition located at $x_0 = 0$. I've modified my code but didn't test it yet